# Creating a function that converts variables as factors in R

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to create a function that takes a dataframe with numerical variables and convert it to factor variables. I mean, I want a new dataframe with the old variables as factors. This is what my code have.

```
 prueba <- function(df){
  for(i in df){df= as.data.frame(i,stringsAsFactors =TRUE)}
print(df)  
}
```

and this is what I've got

```
V=prueba(saber11[2:3])
class(V)
[1] "data.frame"

class(V$i)
[1] "factor"
```

When I want to see my dataframe, I have the following

```
View(V)
```

[image]

It means that the function just pick the first column. What can I do?

This is what saber11[2:3] have

[image]

Comment: @akrun done. It is a picture with the data frame partially

Comment: Try the function in the solution

Comment: I tried, but R says that is NULL

Comment: In your function you are not returning anyting it it `print` which doesn't have a return value.  But in my function, I am returning the data

Comment: Yeah. I save the "prueba" function as a simbol, like A<- prueba(df). I want to save "A" as dataframe and the columns of A as factors.

Comment: Please check the solution I posted with a reproducble example

Comment: You must use a for loop, right? Otherwise dplyr is very intuitive:
`df%>%mutate(across(where(is.numeric), as.factor))` would do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to convert to `factor` column, change the `for` loop by looping over the sequence of columns of data, and assign each column after converting to `factor`

```
preuba <- function(df) {
     for(i in seq_along(df)) {
            df[[i]] <- factor(df[[i]])
          }
       df
 }
```

-testing

```
saber11 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:3, ESTU1 = c('a', 'b', 'c'),
       ESTU2 = c('F', 'F', 'F'))

out <- preuba(saber11[2:3])
str(out)
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ ESTU1: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3
# $ ESTU2: Factor w/ 1 level "F": 1 1 1
```

---

Also, we can do this much easily in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
saber11 %>%
    mutate(across(2:3, factor))
```

Or based on class

```
saber11 %>%
    mutate(across(where(negate(is.factor)), factor))
```

---

Or with `lapply`

```
i1 <- !sapply(saber11, is.factor)
saber11[i1] <- lapply(saber11[i1], factor)
```

Comment: Yes. It works! It's funny, because doesn't worked with the saber11 data set, but it work with another. Anyway, that was what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @ManuelVargas probably because you may have modified the original object with your function

Comment: Yes, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, collect the indices of columns which are not factors, and then turn those columns to factors:

```
prueba <- function(df)
{
  i <- sapply(1:ncol(df), function(x) !is.factor(df[,x]));
  df[,i] <- lapply(df[,i], as.factor)
  df
}
```